# Can I use bootstrapping to evaluate the effectiveness of a clinical intervention on a small sample?

Tags: bootstrap, clinical-trials

I am doing an MSc in occupational therapy, which is concerned with evaluating how effective an occupational therapy intervention is on increasing individual's with learning disabilities daily living skills. I am working with a very small sample (5 to 8 people) and was planning on using a non-standardised assessment to assess individual's perception of their performance (on a scale of one to ten), as well as a Likert scale detailing their actual performance ability (on a scale of 1 to 5). I was thinking of taking baseline data of both measures for each individual and then carrying out a 2-3 week intervention and re-assessing. I was wondering if bootstrapping would be appropriate to analyse this data and show if the intervention is effective or not? Also is parametric bootstrapping the best method to use for this research?
Thanks a million for taking the time to read this,
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be putting the cart before the horse.  With such a small sample size, you might not even need statistics to make your point about observed effects.  Statistics and significance tests are best used for extracting counterintuitive signals from noisy data with complex structures.  In your case, with two time periods and 5-8 people, you could make you point if you just plot the data and write about it.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrapping involves resampling with replacement which can produce resampling bias on small samples. On small samples I think it better to use permutation testing which involves resampling without replacement and thus avoids resampling bias.

Comment: Welcome @Davester. Would you mind expanding on your answer a little bit, like explaining why and how resampling with replacement leads to resampling bias and why is it better to use a permutation test? Preferably also provide an illustration with e.g., a short R script and references? That would be a great help to the OP.